# How to make many comboboxes with same options

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, combobox, drop-down-menu

I have a page with many comboboxes with same options. Diferences is selected value only. Now I render all of them, and it take much time and about 2Mb traffic.
I would like to have "fake" comboboxes with only one option, that is selected. Other options must be in only one exemplar, and render itself when I click on some fake combobox to change it value.

Comment: Perhaps Inheritance would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this approach](http://www.billsternberger.net/asp-net-mvc/dynamically-populate-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc/). You can then get the data once, and bind to all the drop downs.

Comment: As I understand this approach push all data into DOM model and it wiil stay too big. I don't want to keep so many copies in my DOM model.